# Cross compiling, library gmp not found

Tags: compiling, gcc, cross-compilation

I'm trying to cross compile [StrongSwan](http://www.strongswan.org) package on Ubuntu for Synology NAS using official Synology toolchain.

```
Host:
hostname = ubuntu
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.8.0-32-generic
uname -s = Linux

Target:
Synology:
- model DS213+
- CPU: Freescale QorIQ P1022
- Arch: PowerPC
- Endianness: Big Endian
- Linux 2.6.32
- uname -a:
Linux LupoDiskStation 2.6.32.12 #3776 SMP Sat Aug 17 02:11:24 CST 2013 ppc
GNU/Linux synology_qoriq_213+
```

When I run ./configure, I get error:

> configure: error: GNU Multi Precision library gmp not found

Configure command:

```
env CC=/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-gcc \
LD=/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-ld \ 
RANLIB=/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-ranlib \ 
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/include -mcpu=8548 -mhard-float -mfloat-gprs=double" \ 
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/lib" \ 
./configure \ 
--host=powerpc-unknown-linux \ 
--target=powerpc-unknown-linux \ 
--build=i686-pc-linux \ 
--prefix=/usr/local
```

If I run ./configure without extra parameters (with ubuntu gcc), I get no errors.
I can also successfully compile helloworld.c with synology toolchain.

I've following GMP packages installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep gmp
gmpc                        install
gmpc-data                   install
gmpc-dev                    install
libgmp-dev                  install
libgmp10                    install
libgmp3-dev                 install
libgmp3c2                   install
libgmpada2                  install
libgmpxx4ldbl                   install
```

Header file is under /usr/include/gmp.h.

Any idea how to include that gmp.h ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now.
I had to download gmp, cross compile it and copy files to /usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/include dir.

Comment: how did you do all that?

Comment: As @tatsu said, how did you do all that?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this will help  in Ubuntu 18.04?

`sudo apt install libgmp-dev`

Comment: Confirmed working

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I read into the configure file try.

```
./configure \ 
--host=powerpc-unknown-linux \ 
--target=powerpc-unknown-linux \ 
--build=i686-pc-linux \ 
--prefix=/usr/local \
--libdir="/usr/include"
```

Comment: I've added --libdir="/usr/include" to the end of my configure command (including other flags: CC=/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-gcc, ...) but it doesn't help. Maybe it would work if I replace original GCC commands with links to "powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-gcc" or something ?